# TensorFlow get values in a placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

I'm new with TensorFlow. I have some issues understanding. I would like to see the values inside the placeholder when I feed them

```
most simplified example :
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float,[2,2]
Y = X

sess.run(Y,feed_dict={X:[[1,2],[3,4]]})
```

Did a command as:

```
print(sess.run(Y))
```

Result:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

e.g. I don t need the shape, type... of the placeholder but the content.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please place your solution below as an answer, not in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping me :) It's my first post...

Comment: No worries. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder must be feed:

```
print(sess.run(Y,feed_dict={X:[[1,2],[3,4]]}))
```